# Django Filter | Collapsed by Default

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, customization

I have a Django admin panel. In list filter I have a lot of filters. So when loading the page for the first time its not a pleasant sight to see all the filters so what I am trying to do is hide list filter by default and then if user clicks on it it opens up. Is there any option in Django admin to handle this? How can I make the filters collapsed by Default?

Answer (score -1):

I happened upon your question while looking for a way to have my fieldsets in the admin panel be collapsible but not collapsed by default.

I'm following this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/

Here's a code snippet:

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Question information',               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
]
```

Adding the collapse class to the 'Date information' fieldset made it collapsed by default and provides a show/hide button.